# What are the elementary divisors of this special matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Can someone explain how I can calculate the elementary divisors over $\mathbb{Z}$ (and over $\mathbb{R}$) of the following matrix:

$$\begin{pmatrix}2 & -1 \cr -1 &\ddots &\ddots\cr &\ddots & \ddots & -1\\  &&-1 &2 \end{pmatrix}?$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Use induction to compute the Smith Normal Form of the slightly more general matrix $$\pmatrix{a & b & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\ -1 & 2 & -1 & 0 & \cdots& 0 \\ 0 & -1 & 2 & -1 & \cdots & 0 \\ & & & \ddots & \\ & & & -1 & 2 & -1}$$

Comment: Can I work directly from the explicit eigenvalue decomposition? The eigenvalues are explicitly $-4(n+1)^2\sin(\pi j/(2(n+1)))^2$ for $j=1,\ldots,n$.

Comment: Well, I guess you could use the eigenvalues to determine the rank of the matrix (i.e., by counting the number of non-zero eigenvalues), which is all that is needed for determining the elementary divisors over $\Bbb R$. But this approach won't help with finding the elementary divisors over $\Bbb Z$. Whereas, if you find the elementary divisors over $\Bbb Z$ first (by computing the Smith Normal Form over $\Bbb Z$), then you immediately get the rank (and hence the elementary divisors over $\Bbb R$) for free.